# Biblatex Customization for TV-Series and Episodes in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I'm having difficulties customizing my Biblatex style in Overleaf to format series and episodes in my bibliography. I'd like the series name to appear in small caps and have fields like "Director," "Cinematography," etc. displayed correctly.

So far, I've made the following customizations, but it's not working as expected:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textbf{#1}}
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
\DeclareFieldFormat[title]{title}{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[title]{episodetitle}{``#1''}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{tvseries}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}\addspace%
  (\printfield{country}, \printfield{year})\addspace%
  \printfield{network}\addspace%
  \printfield{headwriter} (HW.), \printfield{director} (R.), \printfield{cinematography} (K.), \printfield{editing} (Sch.)\addperiod\addspace%
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{tvepisode}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}\addspace%
  (\printfield{country}, \printfield{year})\addspace%
  \printfield{network}\addspace%
  \printfield{headwriter} (HW.), \printfield{director} (R.), \printfield{cinematography} (K.), \printfield{editing} (Sch.)\addperiod\addspace%
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

Could someone help me find the error or suggest a better solution?

Thank you in advance for your help!